seleccionar todo lo que hay en un combobox al detectar que hay 3 caracteres en un entry de customtkinter
en customtkinter, he hecho un codigo para que cuando haya 3 caracteres en un entry, vaya automaticamente a un combobox y se seleccione todo lo que hay en él.
el codigo del entry es este:
**if len(event.widget.get()) == 2:
        CBthora.focus_set()
        CBthora._tk_widget.select_range(0, ctk.END)**

el CBthora es un combobox
con ese codigo va al combobox pero no se selecciona lo que hay, y se pone el cursor al final.
como podria hacer para que se seleccionara todo lo que hay en el combobox?
esperaba que funcionara
